# Spring autowire by constructor not working without setter method

Tags: spring, autowired, constructor-injection

Here is my Spring xml config:

```
    <beans profile="test">
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- hsqldbDataSource bean for testing purposes -->
    <bean id="hsqldbDataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="shutdown">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <props>
                        <prop key="dataSource.url">${hsqldb.url}</prop>
                        <prop key="dataSource.user">${user}</prop>
                        <prop key="dataSource.password">${password}</prop>
                    </props>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource" />
                <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
                <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="5" />
                <property name="minimumPoolSize" value="1" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- execute a script to create tables after creation of bean for in-memory HSQLDB -->
    <jdbc:embedded-database id="hsqldbDataSource" type="HSQL">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql" />
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data.sql"/>
    </jdbc:embedded-database>

    <bean id="daoManager" class="com.d.DAOManager" autowire="constructor">
       <property name="dataSource" ref="hsqldbDataSource"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And my DAOManager class:

```
public class DAOManager {

private DataSource dataSource;
private Connection connection;

@Autowired
public DAOManager(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}
```

And here I call get my daoManager bean.

```
public static DAOManager createHSQLDBDAOManager() {
    LOG.info("Setting up datasource to in-memory HSQLDB");
    ConfigurableEnvironment env = (ConfigurableEnvironment)applicationContext.getEnvironment();
    env.setActiveProfiles("test");
    applicationContext.load("classpath:/applicationContext.xml");
    applicationContext.refresh();
    DAOManager daoManager = applicationContext.getBean("daoManager", DAOManager.class);
    return daoManager;
}
```

Why is it complaining if I remove the setter method? I don't need it. If I remove the @Autowired before the constructor (it also works) it's just useless and not using the by constructor autowire function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to remove the property value of the daoManager bean

```
<bean id="daoManager" class="com.d.DAOManager" autowire="constructor"/>
```